# Firefox 52 after update has no sound (ALSA)

Tags: firefox, alsa, pulseaudio, bunsenlabs

Firefox has no sound after updating to version 52. I am using Debian/Bunsenlabs with ALSA as my main sounddriver.

Is it possible to get Firefox play sound without installing PulseAudio?

Comment: Firefox does support this through a configure option.  It seems your distribution does not enable that option.  You could build from source; see [this answer on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/892267)

Answer (score 2):

Since version 52, Firefox is built by default with only pulseaudio support.

So if you really can't use pulse, you'll have to rebuild firefox to enable the alsa support.

Answer (score 2):

So in version 52, Firefox ships with pulseaudio only out of the box. You can still compile firefox yourself with ALSA. Some distro's re-enabled it again, some chose not to because they are afraid it will break soon now Mozilla is not supporting it.

People saying Firefox ESR 52 does support ALSA. I just installed it, I can confirm it doesnt.

Me, I am fed up with firefox. First the DRM (netflix) ordeal, now dropping ALSA support. Which forces us to use Pulseaudio. I am jumping ship to Chrome.